# How to implement recursive query in laravel builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have mysql database query and i want to implementing laravel query builder

```sql
with recursive dates as (
    select date('2021-01-01') date
    union all
    select dates.date + interval 1 day from dates where dates.date < '2021-01-31'
)
select dates.date, count(payments.id)
from dates
left join payments on date(payments.created)=dates.date
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell, the only way to add a `WITH` clause to a query is to use raw sql.

```php
$rawSql = <<<SQL
with recursive dates as (
    select date('2021-01-01') date
    union all
    select dates.date + interval 1 day from dates where dates.date < '2021-01-31'
)
select dates.date, count(payments.id)
from dates
left join payments on date(payments.created)=dates.date
group by 1;
SQL;

$results = DB::select($rawSql);
```

If you need to change some values, you can do so with bindings.

```php
$rawSql = <<<SQL
with recursive dates as (
    select date('?') date
    union all
    select dates.date + interval 1 day from dates where dates.date < '?'
)
select dates.date, count(payments.id)
from dates
left join payments on date(payments.created)=dates.date
group by 1;
SQL;

$results = DB::select($rawSql, ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-31']);
```

---

## EDIT

Using `staudenmeir/laravel-cte`, you can write the WITH Clause like this:

```php
withRecursiveExpression('dates', function ($rec) {
    $rec->selectRaw("date('2021-01-01') date")
        ->unionAll(function ($uni) {
            $uni->selectRaw('dates.date + interval 1 day')
                ->from('dates')
                ->whereRaw("dates.date < '2021-01-31'");
        });
})
```

The recursive part of the query kept throwing an error if I used bindings, so unfortunately, the dates are passes in raw.

In theory, this syntax should work for the complete query.

```php
$res = DB::query()
    ->withRecursiveExpression('dates', function ($rec) {
        $rec->selectRaw("date('2021-01-01') date")
            ->unionAll(function ($uni) {
                $uni->selectRaw('dates.date + interval 1 day')
                    ->from('dates')
                    ->whereRaw("dates.date < '2021-01-31'");
            });
    })
    ->select('dates.date', DB::raw('count(payments.id)'))
    ->from('dates')
    ->leftJoin('payments', DB::raw('date(payments.created)'), 'dates.date')
    ->groupByRaw('1')
    ->get();
```

The generated SQL is slightly different.

```sql
with recursive `dates` as (
    (select date('2021-01-01') date)
    union all
    (select dates.date + interval 1 day from `dates` where dates.date < '2021-01-31')
)
select `dates`.`date`, count(payments.id)
from `dates`
left join `payments` on date(payments.created) = `dates`.`date`
group by 1
```

Comment: OP's just using the `WITH` clause to generate a list of dates; that could easily be generated on the Laravel end and provided with a `whereIn` clause. A direct translation isn't necessary.

Comment: In this case, yes. But that might not be a great idea if the date list grows too big. whereIn adds a binding per element.

Comment: I'd like to see if/how the laravel cte extension https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte could be used for this

Comment: @ysth there you go.

Comment: Thanks. I commonly used ```staudenmeir/laravel-cte``` to build the query. but i just want to do with laravel query builder purly.